# Named_scope with joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Can someone help me understand how to convert this sql query to a named_scope or maybe a method?

**Background**: A trip can have many trip_runs. I'm trying to be able to say TripRun.upcoming and return only valid runs from valid trips based on the following query

```
SELECT r.*
FROM trip_run r
LEFT JOIN trips t
ON r.trip_id = t.id
WHERE r.starts_on > NOW()
AND t.is_booked = 1
AND t.is_cancelled IS NULL
```

thank you

Comment: Are you using rails 3 or rails 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Joshua's answer, but for rails 2.3:

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trip_runs
  named_scope :booked, :conditions => 'is_booked = 1 AND is_cancelled IS NULL'
end

class TripRun < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trip
  named_scope :upcoming, :conditions => 'starts_on > NOW()'
end

Trip.booked.trip_runs.upcoming
```

or alternatively:

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trip_runs
end

class TripRun < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trip
  named_scope :upcoming,
              :conditions => 'trip.is_booked = 1 AND trip.is_cancelled IS NULL
                              AND trip_runs.starts_on > NOW()', 
              :joins => :trip
end

TripRun.upcoming
```

That will use an INNER JOIN not a LEFT JOIN, but since you're looking for rows with trip.is_booked set to a non-null value, the results will be the same and the query will be no slower.

Answer (score 2):

this assumes you're using Rails 3 and AREL. Edit your model files for Trip and TripRun like so:

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :trip_runs
    scope :booked, where("is_booked = 1 and isnull(is_cancelled)")

end

class TripRun < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :trip
    scope :upcoming, where("starts_on > NOW()")

end
```

Then access like this:

```
Trip.booked.trip_runs.upcoming
```

There are lots of ways to mix and match these patterns to get similar effects and create methods to access the data.

Comment: I'm using 2.3.5. I made syntax adjustments for the named_scopes, but when I tried to chain them together like listed above, it didn't work.

Comment: I think you have them reversed. The `Trip`s are `booked` or `cancelled` and the `TripRun`s are `started_on`.

Comment: Alassiter... this will require Rails 3, I believe. T, good point, oops. I'll edit.